# Changing a program's display name in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

How can I change the name of a program that shows up in dialogs like "Open with..." on Windows 7? In particular, I'd like to make this dialog

[image: "open with" menu displaying "Foxit Reader 4.1, Best Reader for Everyday Use..."]

simply say "Foxit Reader" or "Foxit Reader 4.1" without the slogan attached.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have tried some resource editors but they all sucked, then I managed to change the executable’s entry in the following registry key and it worked for me, without need for a resource editor at all:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache
```

Comment: In my case, the registry entry was located in a slightly different folder, but I'm still accepting this because it makes the point that all you have to do is find a registry entry and change it. I just used the registry editor's built-in search tool on the string "source code editor" to find Notepad++'s entry, for example.

Answer (score 5):

The executable description is pulled from the executable itself, from the Version resource, in the FileDescription field

You can use a Resource Editor to modify the executable and change the description.  This is editing the notepad++ description from "Notepad++: a free (GNU) source code editor" to "Notepad++ Hum":

[image]

Here is the dialog afterwards:

[image]

Comment: Notepad++ was the first program I changed!

Comment: This doesn't really work. It is not enough to change the metadata stored with the executable you are editing. Are you sure you are not doing anything else?

Comment: @CorporateGeek Yes I am sure nothing else was done.

Comment: On my computers it doesn't work. There must be some additional work needed in the Windows Registry.

Answer (score 3):

The information seems to be aquired from the "version info" in the program itself, it is the file description.  "Resource hacker" will show that. lets assume that you have the rights to alter it , you can just edit the text there, "compile script", then save the program back out.

Not done yet, because it is also stored in the MUI in the registry, so you can search for it in the registry, and remove it from the MUI, or do a MUI rip removing all of them.
If you change it just in the registry MUI it might stick for a while.

Observe the same information being provided via the explorer in the "baloon" when hovering over the program , or by setting the "file description" item as one of the columns.

Messing with a programs resources , using that method doesnt work for some things, and changing things can rarely make a program work different/worse. Resource hacker saves a file called filename.original , when you do a save over the original. That file is the backup.